# SFML undefined reference to `_setjmp'

Tags: cmake, sfml

I was following BarjiLives tutorial to install SFML to VScode but then I get this error whenever I have to use mingw32-make

```
C:\Users\rtbla\OneDrive\Desktop\Build>mingw32-make
[ 15%] Built target sfml-system
[ 16%] Built target sfml-main
[ 40%] Built target sfml-window
[ 51%] Built target sfml-network
[ 52%] Linking CXX shared library ..\..\..\lib\sfml-graphics-2.dll
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/rtbla/OneDrive/Desktop/SFML-2.5.1/extlibs/libs-mingw/x64/libfreetype.a(sfnt.c.obj):sfnt.c:(.text+0x5614): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/12.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:/Users/rtbla/OneDrive/Desktop/SFML-2.5.1/extlibs/libs-mingw/x64/libfreetype.a(smooth.c.obj):smooth.c:(.text+0x77a): undefined reference to `_setjmp'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [src\SFML\Graphics\CMakeFiles\sfml-graphics.dir\build.make:612: lib/sfml-graphics-2.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:307: src/SFML/Graphics/CMakeFiles/sfml-graphics.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make: *** [makefile:135: all] Error 2
```

I haven't really tried anything yet, but I just want it to work!

Comment: Likely because you build with a MinGW flavor different than the one used for building these pre-build binaries of freetype in SFML source code: https://en.sfml-dev.org/forums/index.php?topic=28647.0